# Sigmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, vector

Вылетает ошибка sigmentation fault в Qt при попытке добавить в вектор (STL) элемент класса.
Упорно не понимаю, в чём проблема, потому что цикл (в котором и реализовано помещение элемента) работает в другой части программы.

Вот код, ниже поясню, что происходит:

```
for (QString &element : dirList)
    {
        QDir export_folder(element);
        export_folder.setNameFilters(QStringList() << "*.jpg" << "*.jpeg" << "*.png");
        QStringList tempFileList = export_folder.entryList();

        for (QString &element : tempFileList)
        {
            Photo temp(element);
            photoList->push_back(temp);
        }
    }
```

На всякий случай, захватил чуть предшествующей логики. До момента помещения всё отлично работает. В Другой части программы (не вижу смысла код кидать, но могу, если надо будет) та же логика но без цикла с `dirList`, и список файлов `tempFileList` получен другим методом (то же предусмотренным Qt).

Объясните, пожалуйста, как при помещении элемента `Photo` в `Vector<Photo>` используя метод этого же вектора может возникать sigmentation fault?
Я даже вообразить такого не мог.

P.S.

- Дело не в element, компилятор отличает один от другого
- Конструктор копирования в Photo так же проверен, да и, опять же, этот
  самый конструктор справляется с ровно такой же задачей в другом
  месте
- В процессе программы есть new и delete, но всё это я тщательно
  проверил (Да и может ли оно повлиять?)

И на всякий случай, сделал шаг с заходом, ошибка вылетает в файле stl_vector.h её я выложу скриншотом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас, судя по значениям в правой части скриншота, `this` является нулевым указателем. То есть `photoList` - нулевой указатель.

Comment: @AnT в яблочко. Я определение вектору дал в том месте, куда программа не всегда заходит. Спасибо большое!